# error login form symfony

Tags: symfony, authentication

I'm trying to install a personnal login form with symfony2 and it's always return bad credential User.
Here is my code:
my controller:

```
namespace BO\UserBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception;
use BO\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use BO\UserBundle\Form\UserAddType;

class UserController extends Controller{

public function addUserAction(){

    if(!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
        throw new Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException("Operation denied");
    $oUser = new User();
    $oFormUser = $this->createForm(
                                    new UserAddType(), 
                                    $oUser,
                                    array(
                                        'action' =>             $this->generateUrl("bo_user_add"),
                                        'method' => "POST"
                                    )
            );
    $oEM = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager ();
    if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == "POST"){

        $oFormUser->handleRequest($this->get('request'));

        if($oFormUser->isValid()){
            $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($oUser);
            $password =     $encoder->encodePassword($oUser->getPassword(),$oUser->getSalt());
            $oUser->setPassword($password);

            $oEM->persist($oUser);
            $oEM->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute("bo_user_log_in");            
        }


    }



    return $this->render("BOUserBundle:user:add.html.twig",array("form" => $oFormUser->createView()));


}
}
```

and my user entity

```
namespace BO\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity as unique;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BO\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @unique(fields="email", message="email already exists")
 * @unique(fields="username",message="user's already exists")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $username;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", unique=true, length=255)
     * @assert\Email(message="Invalid Email")
     */    
    private $email;
    /**
     * @var string
     * @assert\NotBlank(message="ne peut pas être null")
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length= 255)
     * @assert\NotBlank(message="salt ne peut pas être null")
     */
    private $salt;
    /**

     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BO\UserBundle\Entity\Role", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */

    private $roles;
    /**
     *
     * @var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
        $this->isActive = true;

    }
    public function eraseCredentials(){

    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *@inheritDoc
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *@inheritDoc
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *@inheritDoc
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }


    /**
     * Get roles
     *@inheritDoc
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *@inheritDoc
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Add roles
     *
     * @param \BO\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles
     * @return User
     */
    public function addRole(\BO\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles)
    {
        $this->roles[] = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove roles
     *
     * @param \BO\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles
     */
    public function removeRole(\BO\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles)
    {
        $this->roles->removeElement($roles);
    }
    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize(){
        return serialize(array($this->id));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($s){
        list($this->id,) = unserialize($s);
    }    

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $UI){
        return $this->username === $UI->getUsername();
    }

}
```

and finally my security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    BO\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
        algorithm: sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations: 0


role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
    printsign_user:
        entity: { class: BO\UserBundle\Entity\User, property: username }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    printsign:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider:  printsign_user
        form_login:
            login_path: bo_user_log_in
            check_path: bo_user_log_check
            default_target_path: bo_user_add
        logout:
            path: bo_user_log_out
            target: bo_user_log_in

        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/articles, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

the view:

```
   {% extends "::base.html.twig"%}

{% form_theme form "BOUserBundle:override:UserLogin.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}
    {{ title }}
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
    {% if zErrors is not null %}
    {{ zErrors.message }}
    {{ last_user }}
    {% endif%}
        {{ form_start(form) }} 
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            <input type="submit" value="envoyer" class="btn btn-primary" />
        {{ form_end(form) }}   
{% endblock %}
```

so it's still always credentials even I use textplain to encode or sha512.
Your help is very appreciate.
thanks